# PCL organized point cloud seems to be unorganized

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library, pcl, lidar-data

I just came across something weird while dealing with organized point clouds.
I am trying to access a point using `cloud->at(row,col)`, but get the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
> 'pcl::UnorganizedPointCloudException'   what():  : Can't use 2D
> indexing with an unorganized point cloud

The thing is, I checked whether the cloud is organized and it claims to be!

```
cloud->isOrganized(): 1
cloud->width: 1024
cloud->height: 128
```

Does someone have an idea what I could be doing wrong?